# Create varable or perturbed timer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I am using a timer to display elements of an array in a timed sequence. I would like to vary or "perturb" the timer to give it a more natural feel. Is there any way to vary or perturb the count of the time using a random variable or something.

Here is the code using the timer:

```
    let strings = [["First down. Run up the middle","run"],["Second down. Screen pass, incomplete","pass"],["Third down. Incomplete pass","pass"],["Fourth down. Punt","punt"],

    var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true){ t in
                speaking = names[count][1]
               //delay here using a random variable.
let delta = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))/8
//Following line does not compile and gives error
//Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delta) { 
                self.post(self,strings[count][0])
            }       
                 count += 1

                if count >= num {
                    t.invalidate()
                }
            }
```

Comment: You could run the timer some multiple faster than the actual interval you need and then have some if statement inside it that (via a random variable or whatever) decides whether to actually fire or to continue to the next firing of the timer.

Comment: If you run it excessively fast, say double time, then you will always need to skip at least once..and occasionally more for variation.  So seems you need to keep track of whether last cycle was a skip or not.  How would you do this.

Comment: With a variable?

Comment: bool. ok that might work. will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the timer some multiple faster than the actual interval you need and then have some `if` statement inside it that (via a random variable or however you want to implement it) decides whether to actually fire or to continue to the next firing of the timer.

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 20, repeats: true){ t in
    if self.shouldDoTheThingAgain() {
        self.doTheThing()
    }
}
```

Assuming you have some methods that keep track of how many times you've already done the thing (e.g. via some property) and that actually do the thing you want to do.